# How can I display custom year on my system?

Tags: date, time

As you know, most countries use the notion of the "Common Era", which is traditionally linked to the Christian religion. For instance, Unix epoch time is being counted from January 1, 1970. However, if using Unix epoch itself as a point of reference, this same date would be displayed as January 1, 1; January 1, 2020 would be January 1, 51 etc.

How can I tweak my system so that it would display the current year according to this custom frame of reference, and automatically change it each new year as needed?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to build a custom *locale definition*, which would essentially be a straight copy of the locale you have used normally so far, except for a custom name and the `era` parameters in the LC_TIME part of the locale definition. You might also need to adjust the date formatting strings to display the years according to your alternative calendar.

Here's a link to the Single Unix Specification's definition of the standard syntax of locale definitions: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xbd/locale.html

You would then use the `localedef` command (or its `locale-gen` wrapper script in Debian/Ubuntu and related distributions) to build a binary representation of your custom locale, and install it in the proper location. After that it should be just a matter of setting the `LC_TIME` environment variable to tell the system that you want to use your custom locale in matters related to displaying time values. The system-wide default value for this variable can often be defined in either `/etc/default/locale` or `/etc/sysconfig/i18n` or by using the `localectl` command, depending on distribution.

(This is also how the Japanese way of counting years of each reigning emperor is handled: on 1 May 2019, as the new emperor Naruhito ascended the throne, it started a new era in the Japanese calendar, and so year 2019 is presented in Japanese traditional calendar as Reiwa 1/Heisei 31. Reference: https://www.ewc.co.jp/Pages/Information/CalendarEN.aspx)

Doing it this way, your system will keep the capability to present the time in the "Common Era" calendar also, which is important for things like email headers: sending email with unexpected year numbers would be a good way to get your outgoing email filtered as spam by other mail servers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

The time measurement inside the Linux kernel has a fixed format.

However, different time formats can be used for this.  These are defined in "locales".  So, the system would internally still use the US and international standard, but it displays different formats.

One third-party program for reading the system time and displaying it in a different format is [cadate](https://github.com/vinc/cadate).